# Outlook 2013 Autocomplete Function not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autocomplete, exchange-2010

The autocomplete function in Outlook (when you start typing and it auto fills the email addresses) just will not work on this one mailbox. I have tried everything I can imagine including:

- Creating a new profile
- Ensuring all of the boxes are checked in the Options > Send mail settings
- Putting in both Cache and Online mode
- Moving the datastore where the Mailbox is located
- Renaming the Roamcache folder in the program data folder
- Renaming the Autocomplete .dat file
- Creating a new windows profile
- Trying both Office 2010 and 2013
- Trying on different computers

And the kicker, all of the autocomplete items are in OWA. I do not want to try emptying the "Empty Auto-Complete List" for obvious reasons. The infrastructure setup is Windows 7 Pro 64bit with Office 2013 Pro 64bit. The server is Windows 2008 R2 Standard with Exchange 2010 SP2. Everything is patched and up to date. I know that .nk2 files live on the server now with Exchange 2010 and the fact that I can see all the autocomplete entries (ones not in the GAL) makes me think something else is going on here.

Comment: Just an update, I used NK2Edit to view the stream_autocomplete*.dat file and noticed there are more than 1000 entries. In Outlook 2013, the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\AutoNameCheck] which is in 2010 doesn't exsist in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

So ultimately, I used [NK2Edit](http://nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html) from Nirsoft to export the AutoComplete entries to an .nk2 file. Then within outlook, I emptied the autocomplete entries from within outlook. Lastly, I put the .nk2 file in the c:..\Roaming\Outlook folder and ran "Outlook.exe /importnk2" and it imported all of the autocomplete entires back into outlook. Must have been a corrupt entry. Extremely annoying.