# Outlook 2013 name auto-completion

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Recently I've installed MS Office 2011 on OS X and setup a few IMAP accounts in Outlook. And it started auto-completing the email addresses in `To` field right from the start. But now I've installed Outlook 2013 on Win and it doesn't auto-complete anything it just works differently from OS X version.

Can I somehow make it parse my existing emails and get the names from them to the auto-completion list?

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/705607/outlook-2013-autocomplete-function-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just create a new message and add all recipients from your contacts to "To" field, after that close this message without saving. That's it, not you'll get all emails in auto-complete cache.

**Update:**

If there are no contacts in Outlook, you can use **free** [Save Addresses from Messages to Contact Folder](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSaveFolder/) or [Save Addresses from Messages to Contact Group](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSaveGroup/) utilities first on your entire mailbox. After that you'll be able to fill the auto-complete cache as described above. You can then delete all contacts created by utilities if needed.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any contacts in address book. It's empty. But it is empty on OS X too.

Comment: Hmm.. So where do you want Outlook to get emails from for autocomplete?

Comment: I'm not sure. Where did it get them on OS X? Somehow it took all addresses on OS X right from the start(I don't have contacts on OS X either)

Comment: Ok, just updated the answer to include this case (when there are no contacts)